# Achieving Custom sort on selection using Macro

Tags: excel, vba

```
Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
'   Sorting
    Application.DeleteCustomList ListNum:=5
    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Array("FGI Not Shipping Current Quarter" _
        , "PENDING 1st TOTE FROM MFG", "PENDING LAST TOTE FROM MFG", "PENDING CRATING", _
        "PENDING DN", "PENDING PICKUP REQUEST", "PENDING FF")
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Priority").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Priority").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "N2:N16"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
        "FGI Not Shipping Current Quarter,PENDING 1st TOTE FROM MFG,PENDING LAST TOTE FROM MFG,PENDING CRATING,PENDING DN,PENDING PICKUP REQUEST,PENDING FF" _
        , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Priority").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:N16")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
```

How can I write the same code to achieve sorting on selection instead of explicit mention of Range from A1:N16?

[Screenshot_Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM1uN.png)

Comment: `.SetRange Range("A1").CurrrentRegion` (as long as your list is bounded by an empty row/column)

Comment: @TimWilliams, My list is not bounded. I tried this and it's giving error.

Comment: If it's not bounded then how do you want to determine what the range should be?

Comment: The complete data on the sheet. If not possible like that, then how can I bound my data, using table? I also added screenshot of my data. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Your list has an empty row below and an empty column to the right of it - that's wghat I meant by "bounded", so `CurrentRegion` should work.  If that gives you an error, what is the error, and on which line?

Comment: @TimWilliams, Thank you for helping. This worked actually. LOL, I copied your recommendation in Macro and just realized that I had to edit spelling of Current

Comment: My bad - did not spot that typo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DeleteCustomList ListNum:=5
Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Array("FGI Not Shipping Current Quarter" _
    , "PENDING 1st TOTE FROM MFG", "PENDING LAST TOTE FROM MFG", "PENDING CRATING", _
    "PENDING DN", "PENDING PICKUP REQUEST", "PENDING FF")
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Priority").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Priority").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
    "N:N"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
    "FGI Not Shipping Current Quarter,PENDING 1st TOTE FROM MFG,PENDING LAST TOTE FROM MFG,PENDING CRATING,PENDING DN,PENDING PICKUP REQUEST,PENDING FF" _
    , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Priority").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1").CurrentRange
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```